# How to I detect when an animation is stopped and properties updated?

Tags: uwp

If I create and start an animation in the visual layer, I could use [`StopAnimation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Composition.CompositionObject#Windows_UI_Composition_CompositionObject_StopAnimation_) to stop the animation. But when I do that it seems that it takes a while before the animation is stopped and the properties are updated with the latest values. Is there some way around that? In the code below, I wait 10 milliseconds but that only works sometimes.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    SpriteVisual MyVisual;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        PointerReleased += MainPage_PointerReleased;
    }


    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        var compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor;

        MyVisual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();

        MyVisual.Size = new Vector2(80, 80);
        MyVisual.Offset = new Vector3(50, 50, 0);
        MyVisual.Brush = compositor.CreateColorBrush(Colors.Green);

        ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(this, MyVisual);

        var animation = compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();
        animation.InsertKeyFrame(1, new Vector3(300, 50, 0));
        animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        animation.IterationBehavior = AnimationIterationBehavior.Forever;

        MyVisual.StartAnimation(nameof(MyVisual.Offset), animation);
    }

    private async void MainPage_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Position when animation running: " + MyVisual.Offset);

        MyVisual.StopAnimation(nameof(MyVisual.Offset));

        await Task.Delay(10);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Position when animation stopped: " + MyVisual.Offset);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`CompositionScopedBatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionscopedbatch) to solve this. One thing to notice is that the [`Completed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionscopedbatch#Windows_UI_Composition_CompositionScopedBatch_Completed) event is triggered immediately if you have infinite number of iterations (I have no idea why). Here is a sample:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    SpriteVisual MyVisual;
    CompositionScopedBatch ScopedBatch;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        PointerReleased += MainPage_PointerReleased;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        var compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor;

        MyVisual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();

        MyVisual.Size = new Vector2(80, 80);
        MyVisual.Offset = new Vector3(50, 50, 0);
        MyVisual.Brush = compositor.CreateColorBrush(Colors.Green);

        ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(this, MyVisual);

        ScopedBatch = compositor.CreateScopedBatch(CompositionBatchTypes.Animation);

        var animation = compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();
        animation.InsertKeyFrame(1, new Vector3(300, 50, 0));
        animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        // animation.IterationBehavior = AnimationIterationBehavior.Forever;
        // CompositionScopedBatch.Completed is triggered immediately if Infinite is used.
        // Use many iterations instead.
        animation.IterationBehavior = AnimationIterationBehavior.Count;
        animation.IterationCount = 1000000;

        MyVisual.StartAnimation(nameof(MyVisual.Offset), animation);

        ScopedBatch.Completed += CompositionScopedBatch_Completed;

        ScopedBatch.End();
    }

    private void CompositionScopedBatch_Completed(object sender, CompositionBatchCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Position when batch completed: " + MyVisual.Offset);
    }

    private void MainPage_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Position when animation running: " + MyVisual.Offset);

        MyVisual.StopAnimation(nameof(MyVisual.Offset));
    }
}
```