# UWP CompositionObject Animation causes black screen

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

This method is triggered by a click event, the effect works fine except the entire computer screen blacks out every other time this method is called (e.g. 1st time works fine, 2nd time blacks out, 3rd time works fine ...) One time I clicked it too frequently windows 10 prompted that display driver failed and switched to windows basic display (I'm using dual screen). Also when it blacks out, the cursor turns into a busy sign and animation glitches. Did anybody else have this issue?

```
    private async void oscillate()
    {

        SpringScalarNaturalMotionAnimation _springAnimation2= Window.Current.Compositor.CreateSpringScalarAnimation();
        _springAnimation2.DampingRatio = 0.3f;
        _springAnimation2.Period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.02);
        _springAnimation2.InitialValueExpressions["FinalValue"] = "0";
        loginBody= ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(LoginBody);
        loginBody.Offset = new System.Numerics.Vector3(-70, 0, 0);
        loginBody.StartAnimation("Offset.X", _springAnimation2);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch to `CompositionScopedBatch` and create a `bool` field to toggle if the animation is running.  Then register for the `Completed` event to toggle your field back off.  Then you can check this field to say whether you can run the animation.  Or use a dictionary  instead and keep a reference to the animation so you can stop it before starting a new one.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionbatchcompletedeventargs

An example of how to use it is here:
[How to I detect when an animation is stopped and properties updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236441/how-to-i-detect-when-an-animation-is-stopped-and-properties-updated)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on how to stop the animation, I tried  loginBody.StopAnimation("Offset.X"); before the startAnimation call but the problem still persists. Also, _springAnimation is a class variable, I put the declaration inside the method here for the sake of clarity.

Comment: I found out that even if I tried using a bool switch to disable the click event or doing -= {event method} on button control during the animation, the screen still blacks out. The strange thing is that I added break point and clearly saw that the repeatedly click events didn't pass the bool switch, the animation still broke down. It seems like no matter what action I perform, as long as it is immediate after the animation, the screen will black out.

Comment: After inspired by the link you provided, I finally found out what the problem was.... The glitch is not caused by cutting off animation before it finishes, it is because I didn't create my own visual object. I don't know why but apparently putting spring animation on a visual fetched from UI would cause a glitch. I used a workaround where I set the ParentForTransform of the visual fetched from UI to a transparent spriteVisual that I instantiated, and animate that spriteVisual instead. Thanks a lot.